# Android app to read pixels of circular ROI

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing

I want to build an android app to read the pixels of a circular area in an image, any circular area.Can anyone suggest what is the best algorithm i should follow?

Answer (score 0):

Let R be the radius you want to search in. Let px and py be the center of the circle you wish to check.

```
for each row r in image:
    for each col c in image:
        if sqrt((r-py)^2+(c-px)^2)<=R
           // handle pixel because it's in ROI
```

Comment: And you suggest i should get the center and radius using hough transform?

Comment: Are you trying to find a circle? Or just get the ROI of any circular area?

Comment: Yeah, that'll work. Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445102/detecting-hough-circles-android